<material> tag issues
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="default">
  
    <model name="simple_model">
      <link name="link">
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
            <material>
    <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
    <specular>1 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
    <pbr>
        <metal>
          <albedo_map>test.png</albedo_map>
          <normal_map>test.png</normal_map>
        </metal>
      </pbr>
  </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>

This is my .sdf file but when i tried running it the following error is shown:
~/Elec PM/texturing$ ign gazebo minimal_world.sdf
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
free(): invalid pointer
Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 21292:
#31   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732ccbaf1, in QThread::exec()
#30   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732eb875a, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#29   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732f130b7, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#28   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7ad731d193e2, in g_main_context_iteration
#27   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7ad731d712b7, in 
#26   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7ad731d1bd3a, in g_main_context_dispatch
#25   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732f13a66, in 
#24   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732ebcf26, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
#23   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732eb9e39, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#22   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0x7ad73256c712, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#21   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732ee741d, in QObject::event(QEvent*)
#20   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x7ad6ee285f45, in ignition::gui::plugins::RenderThread::RenderNext(ignition::gui::plugins::RenderSync*)
#19   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x7ad6ee2837d2, in ignition::gui::plugins::IgnRenderer::Render(ignition::gui::plugins::RenderSync*)
#18   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732eb9e39, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#17   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0x7ad73256c701, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#16   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7ad732eb9b99, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*)
#15   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gazebo-6/plugins/gui/libGzSceneManager.so", at 0x7ad6ec6fe0e0, in ignition::gazebo::v6::GzSceneManager::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)
#14   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-rendering.so.6", at 0x7ad6ec613c5b, in ignition::gazebo::v6::RenderUtil::Update()
#13   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-rendering.so.6", at 0x7ad6ec66fb95, in ignition::gazebo::v6::SceneManager::CreateVisual(unsigned long, sdf::v12::Visual const&, unsigned long)
#12   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-rendering.so.6", at 0x7ad6ec66c2e4, in ignition::gazebo::v6::SceneManager::LoadMaterial(sdf::v12::Material const&)
#11   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-rendering-6/engine-plugins/libignition-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0x7ad6d53a3872, in ignition::rendering::v6::Ogre2Material::SetTextureMapImpl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Ogre::PbsTextureTypes)
#10   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreNextMain.so.2.2.5", at 0x7ad6d39a3234, in Ogre::TextureGpuManager::_waitFor(Ogre::TextureGpu*, bool)
#9    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreNextMain.so.2.2.5", at 0x7ad6d39a2e76, in Ogre::TextureGpuManager::_update(bool)
#8    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreNextMain.so.2.2.5", at 0x7ad6d3876dcb, in Ogre::ObjCmdBuffer::clear()
#7    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreNextMain.so.2.2.5", at 0x7ad6d3797008, in Ogre::Exception::~Exception()
#6    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738ea5452, in free
#5    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738ea2a43, in 
#4    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738ea0cfb, in 
#3    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738e89675, in 
#2    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738e287f2, in abort
#1    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738e42475, in raise
#0    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7ad738e969fc, in pthread_kill
Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 21219 1000)

How to resolve it? I wanted to use a picture for the side of a box.
Also is there a xacro alternative of the code?
